# Не покрывается тестами замоканые функции

Tags: python, django, юнит-тесты, mock

services.py

```
import blockcypher
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .utils import get_wallet_model


def generate_new_address(user, symbol):
    if isinstance(user, get_user_model()) and get_wallet_model(symbol):
        try:
            r = blockcypher.generate_new_address(coin_symbol=self.coin_symbol, api_key=api_key)
            obj = get_wallet_model(symbol).objects.create(
                user = user,
                private = r['private'],
                public = r['public'],
                address = r['address'],
                wif = r['wif']
            )
            return obj
        except Exception:
            return None
```

При попытке замокать, чтобы каждый раз не дёргать внешний API, пробую так:

```
def fake_generate_new_address(self, user, symbol):
    if isinstance(user, get_user_model()) and utils.get_wallet_model(symbol):
        try:
            r = {
                'address': '1HL7fjCRGKC4EfPRjHVgmLmi7Bmpu8hGps',
                'private': '2a9a2a50252bf2eb24553e70861e1774aa8507af1b9497e1da01fa0086a3dfb7',
                'public': '02053a352366b3bee2e3d0d29b346822706bdf7af3cd00f7ce9d3516010d4a37c4',
                'wif': 'KxeXM1gzy5PMJ47orJiZrBK89DycjPxbq7GVS1KcV7UKAFgFTQJx'
            }
            print(r)
            obj = utils.get_wallet_model(symbol).objects.create(
                user = user,
                private = r['private'],
                public = r['public'],
                address = r['address'],
                wif = r['wif']
                )
            return obj
        except Exception:
            return None


@mock.patch('wallets.services.generate_new_address')
def test_new_address_with_valid_data(self):
    obj = services.generate_new_address(self.user, 'dash')
    assertTrue(isinstance(obj, models.Dash)
```

Но в результате:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так?

Этот пример - лишь один из целого списка. Точно таким же образом, например, не получается покрыть @property и @cached_property моделей.

Comment: Я как-то не совсем понял, как mock тут работает, но по идее всё правильно же: вы заменили настоящий код фейковым — настоящий перестал выполняться, о чём покрытие вам абсолютно правильно и сообщает

Comment: А как добиться покрытия настоящего кода, если там обращения к API у которого есть лимит ?

Comment: Мокать blockcypher.generate_new_address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался с тем, как работает mock.

Часть, удалось покрыть так:

```
def test_new_address_with_valid_data(self):
    import blockcypher
    blockcypher.generate_new_address = mock.MagicMock(return_value={
        'address': '1HL7fjCRGKC4EfPRjHVgmLmi7Bmpu8hGps',
        'private': '2a9a2a50252bf2eb24553e70861e1774aa8507af1b9497e1da01fa0086a3dfb7',
        'public': '02053a352366b3bee2e3d0d29b346822706bdf7af3cd00f7ce9d3516010d4a37c4',
        'wif': 'KxeXM1gzy5PMJ47orJiZrBK89DycjPxbq7GVS1KcV7UKAFgFTQJx'
    })
    obj = services.generate_new_address(self.user, 'btc')
    self.assertTrue(
        isinstance(
            obj,
            models.Btc
        )
    )
```

То есть, при помощи `MagicMock`, можно заменить возвращаемые значения любой функции или класса, даже у импортируемых извне.